# Can't use soap-client. Package cl is deprecated

Tags: warning, cl

Emacs 26.3

CentOS 7.0

Install packages **soap-client 3.2.0** and **cl-lib 0.6**

https://github.com/alex-hhh/emacs-soap-client

https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-lib.html

In my `init.el` I add

```
   (require 'soap-client)
```

But after restart Emacs I get error:

```
Warning (package): Unnecessary call to ‘package-initialize’ in init file
Package cl is deprecated
```

Comment: I suspect you have another question behind what you actually asked. If so, ask it separately. See also [What is the X-Y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5):

1. Something that is deprecated is not unsupported. So it's not true that you cannot use it.
2. A warning is not, at least in Emacs, an error.  It's just a message to let you know something you might not otherwise be aware of.  And many, *many* Emacs warnings are benign in actual use, for various reasons.  You need to understand a warning, and do so in the context of what you're doing, in order to know whether you need to do something about it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Emacs 26, and the cl-lib version you're referring to is for Emacs 24.  Use the built-in package manager: `M-x list-packages`.

- Emacs 26 will probably have cl-lib 1.0 already installed.
- The soap-client you're referring to in github is old (ie. not v3.2.0).
- If you have older versions installed, un-install them.